# Thread doesn't terminate itself after work is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, load

I have the following method which starts my server:

```
    public void EngageServer()
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, _InternalPort);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(RunServer);
        this.listenThread.Start();

        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(CheckPortStatus));
        t.Start(_ExternalPort);
    }
```

The problem is that the Thread `t` keeps running, even after the work is finished, here is the method:

```
private void CheckPortStatus(object portObject)
{
    /*
     * For information about this method functionality 
     * please refer to the information file attached to this project on the folder "Information"
     */
    int port = (int)portObject;
    ComputerInfo computerInfo = ComputerInfo.Instance;
    if (computerInfo.isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        using (WebClient browser = new WebClient())
        {
            string content = browser.DownloadString(Properties.Settings.Default.CheckPortURL.Replace("{0}", port.ToString()));
            if (content.Contains("is responding"))
            {
                InsertLog(1, "TCP port " + port + " is open");
            }
            else
            {
                InsertLog(3, "TCP port " + port + " is closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know the thread keeps running because my CPU gets 35% constantly, but commenting the `t.Start(_ExternalPort);` makes the application run normally.

Also, I can be sure that the works have been done, since I can check the result on my database.

Shouldn't the thread `t` be stopped and disposed after the result from the webpage have been processed (added to the database using the `InsertLog` method)?

Comment: Put some Debug.WriteLines() in and output some times so you can see where it's using the time. Or, use Visual Studio's performance tools to time it (if you have it).

Comment: You don't seem to have any code that's looping and keeping the thread running. I suggest you debug the program and use Visual Studio's Break All feature (the pause button in the IDE) to see what it's doing at the time when it seems to be running abnormally.

Comment: Yes, that was apparently the problem. I changed the code to download Google's html and the app ran normally.